# Application Exit Using With Back Pressed Event

Tags: android, exit, onbackpressed

My app's main activity is "LoginActivity". If user log in one time bypass the Login Activity and app will open Main Activity every time. I want to exit app with back pressed event on Main Activity. If I use "finish();" on Main Activity, my app is working background, I want to app close.,how can I fix that problem.

LoginActivity:

```
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(LoginActivity.this);
    boolean alreadysignIn = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("haveCurrUser", false);
    if (alreadysignIn) {

        GoToMainActivity();
    }


 private void GoToMainActivity() {

    //Using For by-pass to log in Activity.
    //Use for log out.
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
    sharedPreferences.edit().putBoolean("haveCurrUser", true).apply();

    Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
}
```

MainActivity:

```
private long backPressedTime;
....
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (backPressedTime + 2000 > System.currentTimeMillis()) {

        snackbar.dismiss();
        super.onBackPressed();
        finish();
    } else {

        snackbar = Snackbar.make(layoutMainContainer, getResources().getString(R.string.exit_info), Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT);
        snackbar.show();
    }
    backPressedTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
}
```

Comment: Can you please share the code of both LoginActivity.class and MainActivity.class

Comment: I add codes about that, if u want I can share more @yash786

Comment: yes can you share the full code of these 2 classes.?

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

System.exit(0);

in your onBackPressed() method.

Replace finish(); with System.exit(0);

Hope it's the answer you are looking for.

System.exit(0)

The VM stops further execution and your program will exit.

Answer (score 0):

Main Activity use this code

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        finishAffinity();
    }
```